# Lost connection to connected iPhone device when locked

Tags: ios, flutter, debugging

I am developing an iOS app with Flutter and it builds and loads on my connected iPhone. If I lock the iPhone and unlock it within a few seconds, the connection remains, but if I lock the iPhone for about 20 seconds the connection gets lost and I need to rebuild. Is there anything I can do to persist the session while the device is locked?

Comment: I am guessing this is a power saving thing done by apple which disallows polling or something once the screen is turned off. I've checked developer settings and couldn't see an obvious way to turn it off

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came up with a workaround for this by implementing wakelock in debug mode:

```
import 'package:wakelock/wakelock.dart';
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';

if (kDebugMode) {
  Wakelock.enable();
}
```